# How to combine css classes in one imported object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reverse-engineering, css-modules, react-css-modules

I'm currently trying to setup a react app with css-modules. On my research, I stumbled over this weird "compiled" css function representing css class names from css-modules. At least this is what I think. As you can see in the code example, all functions have numbers as name and there are severel css class names combined (e.g. 5721 - content: "content-12UI7d flex-1O1GKY justifyCenter-3D2jYp"). Maybe someone can show me how to setup this kind of css/js import.

Thx Jani

```
5721: function(e, t, o) {
        e.exports = {
            flex: "flex-1O1GKY",
            justifyCenter: "justifyCenter-3D2jYp",
            marginBottom20: "marginBottom20-32qID7",
            size18: "size18-3EXdSj",
            height24: "height24-3XzeJx",
            content: "content-12UI7d flex-1O1GKY justifyCenter-3D2jYp",
            image: "image-2n9YoQ",
            title: "title-rv8Fft marginBottom20-32qID7 size18-3EXdSj height24-3XzeJx",
            formItem: "formItem-HhFqlF marginBottom20-32qID7",
            logout: "logout-237t5C"
        }
    },
5722: function(e, t, o) {
        e.exports = {
            vertical: "vertical-V37hAW flex-1O1GKY directionColumn-35P_nr",
            alignCenter: "alignCenter-1dQNNs",
            marginTop20: "marginTop20-3TxNs6",
            marginBottom20: "marginBottom20-32qID7",
            marginBottom40: "marginBottom40-2vIwTv",
            size18: "size18-3EXdSj",
            height24: "height24-3XzeJx",
            modal: "modal-3YfEfS size18-3EXdSj height24-3XzeJx",
            content: "content-thnEEj vertical-V37hAW flex-1O1GKY directionColumn-35P_nr alignCenter-1dQNNs",
            closeButton: "closeButton-BJGJeO",
            image: "image-2lEAkj marginBottom20-32qID7",
            title: "title-3CgDLA marginBottom40-2vIwTv",
            appPromotion: "appPromotion-2PUSOL marginBottom20-32qID7"
        }
    },
5723: function(e, t, o) {
        e.exports = {
            marginBottom20: "marginBottom20-32qID7",
            marginTop8: "marginTop8-1DLZ1n",
            marginReset: "marginReset-236NPn",
            marginTop4: "marginTop4-2BNfKC",
            modal: "modal-2VIBV8",
            footer: "footer-1oJbSA",
            description: "description-zfMhzy marginBottom20-32qID7",
            name: "name-3ChUIO marginBottom20-32qID7",
            type: "type-3aEJ96 marginBottom20-32qID7",
            cloneInfo: "cloneInfo-1OC_Ee marginTop8-1DLZ1n",
            icon: "icon-3pNFyS",
            error: "error-chiOuv marginTop8-1DLZ1n",
            header: "header-3nFfBB marginReset-236NPn",
            clone: "clone-14QU8p marginTop4-2BNfKC",
            permissionsTitle: "permissionsTitle-2yG7gU marginBottom20-32qID7",
            foreground: "foreground-SshK2E",
            background: "background-6FOJIb",
            switchIcon: "switchIcon-_4Efyi",
            storeChannelOptionSelector: "storeChannelOptionSelector-2rFIBx",
            subtitle: "subtitle-3csUrC"
        }
    },
```

Comment: This is something internal to css-modules. what is it that you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I find the idea interesting to combine classes without using something like JedWatson/classnames or plain js. And I think that I never saw this kind of result from css-modules with numbered functions and combined css classes. I just want to find out how this code was produced.

Comment: For any further readers, I accidentally stumbled over the solution. CSS-Modules lets you combine classes via the composes keyword. I missunderstood the usage in the first place so pls excause me. Greetings Jani  https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules#Composition